# Tombstone physical location in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, tombstone

As I know, Cassandra uses "tombstone" as a delete mark.
Because SSTable is immutable, it marks deleted record by using tombstone.
So, where the tombstone has been marked in SSTable files?
Is it marked in Index file in SSTable or another places?
I want to understand concrete logic of tombstone mark flow.

Answer (score 3):

This [article](http://thelastpickle.com/blog/2011/05/15/Deletes-and-Tombstones.html) from Aaron Morton should give a thorough explanation on how the tombstone and deletion works. Credit should be really attribute to him. If you want to see the tombstone implementation, read [this](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/cassandra/trunk/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/db/RowMutation.java) for more information. Below are some of points extracted from the site to answer this question.

> When a column is deleted a DeletedColumn aka Tombstone is created in
>   Cassandra. The DeletedColumn will have:
>
> name: Name of the column deleted
>
> value: Current server time as seconds since the unix epoch (integer). This is known 
>          as the localDeleteTime and is used during the (cassandra) GC process.
>
> timestamp: As provided by the client
>
> The mutation is then applied to the memtable in one of two ways. If
>   the memtable does not contain the named column for the row it is
>   simply added to the memtable. If there is an existing column it is
>   reconcile() ‘d with the Deleted Column. The new DeletedColumn will
>   replace the existing column if it has a higher (client provided)
>   timestamp. The localDeleteTime is not used for reconciliation. At this
>   point any previous column value in the memtable is lost and will not
>   be persisted to disk.
>
> We now have a tombstone. If there are no other mutations the
>   DeletedColumn will later be persisted to the SSTable just like any
>   other column.

So it is the memtable that has the tombstone mark. The explanation continued; excerpt from the site.

> During a local read for a row value the same reconciliation process
>   that was used during the delete request runs. Multiple row fragments
>   are retrieved from the current memtable, memtables pending flush and
>   SSTables on disk. The fragments are reduced and the columns with the
>   same name reconciled to arrive at the current value.
>
> For example if there is a row fragment in an SSTable for key "foo"
>   that says columns "bar" is "baz", and a DeletedColumn in another
>   SSTable with a higher time stamp when they are reconciled the
>   DeletedColumn will "win". The current view of the row will be that the
>   "bar" column is deleted.